# how to compress the uncompressed avi by ffmpeg or DirectShow.net

Tags: ffmpeg, avi, directshow.net

I have a uncompressed avi file and i want to compress it by program .
how to compress the uncompressed avi  by ffmpeg or DirectShow.net ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using FFmpeg:

- using command line syntax - question for SuperUser
- using underlying `libav*` programmatically - refer to FFmpeg samples (e.g. [one of the tutorials](http://blog.tomaka17.com/2012/03/libavcodeclibavformat-tutorial/) demonstrating the concept)

Using DirectShow.NET:

- as described in [Recompressing an AVI File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377501) on MSDN and implementing the same concept in managed code using DirectShow.NET wrapper